# Is it possible to create collapsible without using JQM in phonegap android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova-2.0.0

I have created an App which has Collapsible block using JQM its working fine. Know what i want to know is it possible to create collapsible block without using JQM. If its possible please give an example.